# php Regular Expression Issues - Can't remove/strip out and replace a string within a string

Tags: php

I have never worked with regular expressions before and I need them now and I am having some issues getting the expected outcome.

Consider this for example:

```
[x:3xerpz1z]Some Text[/x:3xerpz1z] Some More Text
```

Using the php **preg_replace()** function, I want to replace **[x:3xerpz1z]** with <start> and **[/x:3xerpz1z]** with </end> but I can't figure this out. I have read some regular expression tutorials but I am still confused.

I have tried this for the starting tag:

```
preg_replace('/(.*)\[x:/','<start>', $source_string);
```

The above would return:<start>3xerpz1z

As you can see, the "3xerpz1z" isn't getting removed and it needs to be stripped out. I can't hard code and search and replace "3xerpz1z" because the "3xerpz1z" chars are randomly generated and the characters are always different but the length of the tag is the same.

This is the desired output I want:

```
<start>Some Text</end> Some More Text
```

I haven't event tried processing **[/x:3xerpz1z]** because I can't even get the first tag going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use capturing groups `(....)`:

```
$data = '[x:3xerpz1z]Some Text[/x:3xerpz1z] Some More Text';

$result = preg_replace('~\[x:([^]]+)](.*?)\[/x:\1]~s', '<start>$2</end>', $data);
```

pattern details:

```
~         # pattern delimiter: better than / here (no need to escape slashes)
\[x:
([^]]+)   # capture group 1: all that is not a ]
]         
(.*?)     # capture group 2: content
\[/x:\1]  # \1 is a backreference to the first capturing group
~s        # s allows the dot to match newlines
```

Comment: @rwx: I have tested it and it works well! Did you display the `$result` variable? Refresh the page and try again.

Comment: I apologize, that actually does work! My bad, I printed out $data rather then $result, thx!